# RSA encryption and decryption in Python using OpenSSL

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, rsa, pyopenssl

I have public key, private key and encrypted message ( e, n, d, message). I want to encrypt and decrypt with OpenSSL in Python.

I have keys I don't need to generate them. I saw many questions about RSA but all of them creates keys, by `generate` method. I haven't seen questions about performing encryption and decryption.

How do I perform RSA encryption and decryption in Python usomg OpenSSL?

---

What I have is the followings:

```
#Public key:
e="65537"

n="2483790199491205341506001624338547531741771200963322451" \
  "16318655098567854682220895878748602513720919196015584783557" \
  "704400541915850094004767776687012394493261448676783015273985771" \
  "1238030112386627501698642461625407366533907839206541565912321199" \
  "009791795944233570230631191423356738502486763195167267521973031" \
  "6838578210434343067511636079081818744400113533624136339709745782" \
  "32161853372590090308494113224155565481298018056338822080805188480" \
  "139150684063550507331062187412707210886548924698896783031493679037" \
  "3122088161029787856707927049345768779125257912445784686277424030038" \
  "539380288863347855630618237433032833865316901740219"


#Private key
d="152501997096795110757068525202189319208625862269501399381045003" \
  "01373684948285528219578200125958795897780598922907027278290745917" \
  "4083840545807194541888429655727807270271016523695687179904011971106" \
  "46024638603131783118232131092639581621182826911051011196270811088775" \
  "8622627957416117004996969971673524599345136221501081814180958260506967" \
  "05549363779862358358393233189560520163106785535319492545898745183439" \
  "10980478364023104227720426942196244946117979269924656213962726626606" \
  "77452212629548965644705371048342816305068001182195025882564173365857" \
  "07762540909960941277936950557159506459454566798472128560135656506235" \
  "741389170953"


#encrypted message
encoded="187216163520278606105320112446137004408231369834741341053563682" \
        "277774349916058822189964158715390402738262899525931062389534962" \
        "09104749822344117450601254708536373034264130933521987327974000" \
        "255146756518397668069770185737907343422454676477169144712992560" \
        "738066894543224559303296179944700852861503983647039123452966586" \
        "43024446530008588087574157621730825724439869400851215840977916" \
        "767440706251849931986529460039147463908090086303953826751056882" \
        "5732583473943114017472152320746478960753673137088195122814398113" \
        "5288648561417818449968250721180493107501204327582989947582671" \
        "70231934908068721013345590521202959891172540575563129"
```

Comment: You need to show what format your key and message is in and what you've tried. As it stands the question is off topic (for at least 3 different reasons). Besides that, if shown a working option, how would you know it is secure?

Comment: Well, you seem to be right. I'm getting fodder when searching for Python and `RSA_encrypt` and `RSA_decrypt`. Maybe PyOpenSSL lacks the bindings for the functions. I thought this topic would have a few good posts and answers.

Comment: @jww yeah, actually there is a method called importKey which imports the key from the file and I put my key in the file, but my attempts were failed

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for warning, I put what I got (keys and cipher text) but I tried so many things and I can not put them here, it would make the question unreadable, though

Comment: This is pretty clearly an exercise. It uses "raw" RSA (RSA without padding of any kind). The idea of performing an exercise is to try out things you've learned. What library are you using? Or should you create the routines yourself? If so, where are you stuck? Creating the key, deciphering or decoding?

Comment: Thanks for the blast from the past, by the way... I instantly recognized the monkey-ness of the answer!

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, this is an exercise. In the exercise I am supposed to use pyOpenSSL. Where I am stuck is using the library. As I mentioned the question, I can not find appropriate functions to use my datas. I know how RSA works(not deeply). But I can not figure this out this problem. And I did not understand what you mean by monkey-ness?

Comment: This isn't real RSA encryption. The plaintext isn't padded at all. Anyway, you can decrypt it as follows: `plaintext = pow(int(encoded,10),int(d,10),int(n,10)); print hex(plaintext)[2:-1].decode('hex')`

Comment: @MaartenBodewes With three arguments, `pow()` *is* a modular operation.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage thank you for your solution. Could you please explain how you solved it. Especially wonder how you understand that the plaintext  is not padded at first look. You can put it as an answer maybe some people will need it later

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Right, all the more reason to make it into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ciphertext can be decoded without using pyOpenSSL or any other external libraries.

Simply reverse the encryption operation using the formula *m* = *c*<sup>*d*</sup> mod *n* as follows:

```
n="24837..."
d="15250..."
encoded="18721..."
plaintext = pow(int(encoded,10),int(d,10),int(n,10))
print hex(plaintext)[2:-1].decode('hex')
```

The `pow()` operator performs a modular exponentiation operation to calculate `(encoded**d) % n`. In the `print` statement, the resulting value is converted to hexadecimal (removing the first two characters `0x` and the last character `L`), and then decoded as a hexadecimal string to retrieve the original bytes.

Since the message was encoded without using any padding, no further operations are required.